# Repeatedly merge columns within each spanners in a gt table

Tags: r, gt

I am trying to apply a `cols_merge` repeatedly in a gt table. My data consist of summary statistics where that were calculated for multiples variable across several groups: Columns names of the dataframe are constructed this way: `stat_group`. As I have several groups and summary statistics, I want to avoid copy pasting the `cols_merge` as I might want to exclude some groups later.

I tried several approaches  but none of them was satisfying enough as :

- merging gt tables is not possible at the moment, preventing from creating separate gt table for each groups
- `cols_merge` doesn't take in account existing table spanner
- using `mutate(across())` does not work in a gt object

Ideally I would like to use `map` or a `across` like approach to create the spanners and merge the columns for each `group`  with a function like this:

```r
function(gt, group){ 
    gt %>% 
    tab_spanner(columns = contains(group)) %>% 
    cols_merge_n_pct( col_n = contains(paste0("n_",group),col_pct = contains(paste0("prop_",group))) 
}
```

Here is a short example of what I am trying to achieve:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

# Sample data
data <- tibble( "var" = c("var1", "var4", "var3"), 
                "n_group1" = c("10", "10", NA),
                "prop_group1" = c(0.1, 0.1, NA),
                "mean_group1" = c(NA,NA, "1"),
                "sd_group1" = c(NA, NA, "0.1"),
                "n_group2" = c("20", "20", NA),
                "prop_group2" = c(0.2, 0.2, NA),
                "mean_group2" = c(NA, NA, "20"),
                "sd_group2" = c(NA, NA, "0.2"))

data %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_percent(
    columns = starts_with("prop_")
  ) %>% 
  sub_missing(missing_text = "") %>% 
  # Group 1 spanner
  tab_spanner(label = "Group 1", 
              columns = contains("group1")
  ) %>% 
  # Group 2 spanner
  tab_spanner(label = "Group 2", 
              columns = contains("group2")
  ) %>% 
  
  # Group 1 stats
  cols_merge_n_pct( col_n = "n_group1",col_pct = "prop_group1") %>% 
  cols_merge_uncert(col_val = "mean_group1", col_uncert = "sd_group1") %>% 
  cols_merge(columns = c("n_group1", "mean_group1")) %>% 
  # Group 2 stats
  cols_merge_n_pct( col_n = "n_group2",col_pct = "prop_group2") %>% 
  cols_merge_uncert(col_val = "mean_group2", col_uncert = "sd_group2") %>% 
  cols_merge(columns = c("n_group2", "mean_group2"))
```

| var | Group 1 |  | Group 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **n_group1** | **mean_group1** | **n_group2** | **mean_group2** |
| var1 | 10 (10.00%) |  | 20 (20.00%) |  |
| var4 | 10 (10.00%) |  | 20 (20.00%) |  |
| var3 |  | 1 ± 0.1 |  | 20 ± 0.2 |

```r
# Not working
data %>%
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_percent(
    columns = starts_with("prop_")
  ) %>% 
  sub_missing(missing_text = "") %>% 
  # Group 1 spanner
  tab_spanner(label = "Group 1", 
              columns = contains("group1")
  ) %>% 
  # Group 2 spanner , idealy I would like to avoid to manually specify the column in tab_spanner  
  tab_spanner(label = "Group 2", 
              columns = contains("group2")
  ) %>% 
  cols_merge_n_pct( col_n = contains("n_group"),col_pct = contains("prop_group")) %>% 
  cols_merge_uncert(col_val = contains("mean_group"), col_uncert = contains("sd_group")) %>% 
  cols_merge(columns = matches("n_group|mean_group"))
```

| var | Group 1 |  | Group 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **n_group1** | **mean_group1** | **n_group2** | **mean_group2** |
| var1 | 10 |  | 20 |  |
| var4 | 10 |  | 20 |  |
| var3 |  | 1 ± 20 |  | 20 |

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a proper way to handle that, so I went for function that wrap `cols_merge` and apply it to every group based on column's names. Not very elegant, but it works. Here is the function:

```
gt_cols_group_merge <- function(gt_table, group, stat_cols = c("n", "missing"), pattern = NULL , rows = everything() ){ 
  g <- group
  for(i in seq_along(g)){
    columns <-  paste(c(stat_cols), g[i], sep = "_")
    gt_table <- gt_table %>% 
      cols_merge(columns = columns, pattern = pattern, rows = {{rows}} )
  }
  gt_table
}
```

An here a quick example:

```
group <-  c("group1", "group2")
data %>% 
  gt %>% 
  gt_cols_group_merge(group = group, stat_cols =  c("n", "prop"), pattern = "<<{1} ({2})>>") %>%
  gt_cols_group_merge(group = group, stat_cols =   c("mean", "sd"), pattern =  "<<{1} (+/-{2})>>")
```

| var | Group 1 |  | Group 2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **n_group1** | **mean_group1** | **n_group2** | **mean_group2** |
| var1 | 10 |  | 20 |  |
| var4 | 10 |  | 20 |  |
| var3 |  | 1 ± 20 |  | 20 |

Works as expected, the output can be customized using pattern argument.